# How do I fix an error while updating packages cache?

Tags: 11.04, apt, updates

When I try to update in Ubuntu 11.04 after installation, I get the following error

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones 
used instead.
```

I tried the following command still the same error

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Please help me.

Comment: Show the full output of update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy problem. Permissions to download the package weren't there.

Answer (score -1):

exactly check if you have /etc/apt/source.list file over there. if it is, open it and check its structure.

Comment: checked it is not opened.